# java code with files work from eclipse but dont work from cmd

Tags: java, windows, cmd

code:

```
 File folder = new File("src/zipper");
 File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
 File s=listOfFiles[0];
```

Work excellent from eclipse but from the cmd(windows) I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at testFile.main(testFile.java:23)
```

Line 23 is:

```
File s=listOfFiles[0];
```

Zipper is a folder with a lot of folders inside it and each of them has a zip file.

Comment: try passing the full path like c:\myfolder\src and then see what you get. May be where you are running the src folder is not the correct relative path.

Comment: BTW very strange you referencing a file in the `src` folder... this normally is not deployed and should only contain resources used during development.- eclipse normally copies (non java) files to the build (or whatever you named it) folder, but not sure how you configured your project

Comment: @Gagan thanks you! please write your answer and i I will mark it as successful

Comment: @shiraozeri done.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try passing the full path like c:\myfolder\src and then see what you get. May be where you are running the src folder is not the correct relative path.

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles():

> Returns: An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

It would seem that you are getting null because the working directory from where you are launching Java does not hold the src/zipper folders.